# How can I view Ubuntu Files once in Windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I've seen answers on this questions like ext2 explorer, but when I try to find the Ubuntu partition of my hdd, it doesn't show up in Windows Explorer. I can't boot into Ubuntu because every time I do it freezes shortly after I log in, and I can't do anything. I just need to recover a few text files from it and then I can reinstall. Please help!

Comment: This is off topic here. Yes, you mention Ubuntu, however, the issue you have is entirely about Windows. If you want help with Ubuntu, by all means, ask a new question. Otherwise, post this question over at [su]. Tip: Use `ext2fsd`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Windows only supports NTFS and FAT filesystems. Ubuntu uses ext4 formatting. You won't be able to access those partition with Windows without wiping them. But you could ask a question here on AskUbuntu to see if you can solve your login problem. It may be simpler than it sounds!

Comment: `ext2fsd` adds support.

Comment: But, if I remember well, it requires formatting the partition.

Comment: Not the last time I used it

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer to the question you're asking, but it might get you your files.

Instead of logging in using the graphical login, you can try to log into the command-line interface.
If you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or Ctrl+Alt+F6 or something in between), you get a text login prompt. If you're lucky, that might not freeze. If so, you'll be able to copy your files to another drive, like a USB stick or such.